# Linear canonical transformation represented by a unitary operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am reading a paper on Squeezed states which mentions the following fact  "a linear canonical transformation can be represented by a unitary transformation" and then used a operator $\hat{U}$ for making the transformation. My question is,what is a linear canonical transformation, how do we prove the stated fact and how do we compute the form of the operator $\hat{U}$?

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:18096085
Page No. 6-7

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, a linear canonical transformation $e^{\{ F, \cdot\}}$ has a generating function $F$ quadratic in the phase space variables $q$ and $p$.
Upon quantization, the real function $F$ turns into a selfadjoint operator $\hat{F}$. The corresponding unitary operator is $\hat{U}=e^{\frac{1}{i\hbar}\hat{F}}$.

Comment: Any literature recommendations?

Comment: @NamanAgarwal see Moshinsky, Marcos, and Christiane Quesne. "Linear canonical transformations and their unitary representations." Journal of Mathematical Physics 12.8 (1971): 1772-1780